# Ruby on Rails: CSS and skins management

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, admin

I have a skin support in my app. I'm looking for a tool, which will enable the customer (not the programmer, which is current) alter the skins.

Is there an admin tool (gem, plugin) for Rails to manage (edit, create, view) these skins? I looking for some easy solution like `/admin/skins` page where I could do all the stuff, otherwise I'm going to write my own one.

In case there's no such tool - is there any *best practice* example (possible from other language/framework)? What kind of approach is used in other languages/frameworks?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the [theme_support](http://rubygems.org/gems/theme_support) gem a possible solution?

Comment: This is not the something that solves the problem. Although thanks for pointing to a nice gem

Answer (score 0):

This actually depends on what you want styled. I'm not sure if there are any plugins out there that I haven't heard of yet, but personally I'd just do my own skin styler if I was in your shoes.

My idea is either give your users the ability to customize their page entirely ala myspace in which case you just have to create a semantically robust HTML then make a css uploader that will use their css files for the design.

Or you could limit your users to what you want styled so you can still maintain the basic layout of your site. Just give them access to coloring their fonts, resizing or coloring their backgrounds. No floats or whatsoever. In this case, you have to create something that will take a color/font-size as an input and change that depending on what the user picked.